# How to discard particular Severity's in the Rsyslog Server

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I have an rsyslog server that's having the data from multiple remote clients; now I want to discard particular Severity types like `warn` , `info` and `debug` and the rest of the messages I want to be accepted.

I have below config which partially shows `template` and `Rules` to be checked.

In the below config I have commented the all the `Custom conditional Forwarding` because I have other hostnames starts with different names. So, I'm thinking about the way if I can only discard `warn` , `info` and `debug` and rest to come.

```
$template wcc-logs, "/data/SYSTEMS/%HOSTNAME%/messages.log"
#### RULES ############################################
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.#
# Don't log private authentication messages!        #
####################################################
mail.none,authpriv.none,cron.none,news.none,uucp.none,kern.none  ?wcc-logs
*.*              ?wcc-logs
#####################################################################
# Custom conditional Forwarding of messages to the syslog Directory #
###################################################################
#if $fromhost startswith "wc" then {
#  *.crit,*.err,*.emerg,*.alert,*.panic,mail.none,authpriv.none,cron.none,news.none,uucp.none,kern.none  ?wcc-logs
#  & stop
#}

#if $fromhost startswith "sj" then      -?wcc-logs
#& stop

#if $fromhost startswith "vlsj-" then   -?wcc-logs
#& stop
```

In the above configuration you may see I'm using the below Rules in the RULES section assuming that everything should be logged except the First line:

> ```
>  mail.none,authpriv.none,cron.none,news.none,uucp.none,kern.none  ?wcc-logs
> *.*              ?wcc-logs
> ```

rsyslogd 8.24.0

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to discard every log message at the warn, info and debug levels. Is that correct?

Comment: @Haxiel, yes, if there was another cases where partial exclusion may happen that would be interesting to see as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to drop all messages at the `warn`, `info` and `debug` levels and everything else to be logged using the 'wcc-logs' template:

```
*.=warn,*.=info,*.=debug                                                stop
*.*,mail.none,authpriv.none,cron.none,news.none,uucp.none,kern.none     ?wcc-logs
```

The dropped messages will not be available for further processing to any of the following rules in the `rsyslog.conf` file.

If you want to omit the messages at these levels, but still have them available for further processing for other rules down the line, you can extend the single rule to ignore these specific levels:

```
*.*,mail.none,authpriv.none,cron.none,news.none,uucp.none,kern.none,*.!=warn,*.!=info,*.!=debug     ?wcc-logs
```

Comment: Thanks @Haxiel , its interesting to see the logic thanks a mile, let me try these, already +1

Comment: I can even use like `*.*,!=info,*.!=debug     ?wcc-logs` ?

Comment: @pygo If you want to omit the logs at the info and debug levels (which are the lowest two levels), it's better to just flip the logic and use `*.notice ?wcc-logs` instead.

Comment: you mean just  to use  `*.notice ?wcc-logs` rather  `*.*,!=info,*.!=debug ?wcc-logs`  buy i need `warn` also excluded ..

Comment: Sorry for asking too much , i beleive i need all these excluded like you given example `*.=notice,*.=warn,*.=info,*.=debug     stop` i don't even want notice

Comment: @pygo That's fine. The ascending order of the log message levels is debug, info, notice, warning/warn, err/error, crit, alert, emerg/panic. If you only want messages of a certain level and above, it is simpler to specify `*.level ?wcc-logs` instead. That will log all the messages at and above the specified level.