# How to negate certain messages based on negation syntax

Tags: rsyslog

I want to use negation to stop certain messages to be passed on the rsyslog bassed on the `$rawmsg`.

Message exaple like:

```
(root) CMD (LANG=C LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/mrtg /etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg --lock-file /var/lock/mrtg/mrtg_l --confcache-file /var/lib/mrtg/mrtg.ok)
```

I tried but not working:

```
if $rawmsg !contains '(root) CMD ' then  ?wcc-logs
& stop
```

It relates to [previous post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500899/how-to-discard-particular-severitys-in-the-rsyslog-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the expression correctly. In script, you need to use "not" instead of "!". Also, the not must precede the to-be-negated expression. So correct syntax is

```
if not ($rawmsg contains '(root) CMD ') then  {
    ?wcc-logs
    stop
}
```

I have used the parenthesis solely for clarification. I have modernized the if a bit to use the block syntax, which IMHO is easier to grasp.

Doc on script syntax: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/index.html

Comment: Thanks @rainer,  what does it mean `the not must precede the to-be-negated expression` ?

Comment: yes, exactly. This is the case-